# Question on exponential decay

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm looking to show that a continuous function that satisfies $f(x+L)=(1/2)f(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and a constant $L \in \mathbb{R}$ has to be an exponential. I thought about turning it into an ODE but didn't see how. Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: Hint: use first principle of limit calculation . (L' Hospital's rule if required for L-> 0)

Comment: L is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a counterexample, try something like $$f(x)=\dfrac{2-x/L+\lfloor x/L \rfloor}{2^{\lfloor x/L \rfloor}}$$

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a continuous function.

Comment: @Marc: where do you think it is discontinuous?

Comment: My apologies, my mistake.

Comment: You are right! That is a counterexample, i guess my afirmation was too strong, i actually need something slightly weaker, do you mind if i change the question?

Comment: @wannabecapablanca: it might be better to ask a different question and link back to this one. Otherwise the question and answer become anacronistic

Comment: As a note: my answer assumes $L\gt 0$.  It is easily adjusted for $L \lt 0$, while $L=0$ has the unique solution $f(x)=0$

Comment: [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030031/another-question-on-exponential-decay)