# A question about an exponential decay

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f$ be a continuous function satisfies $$f(x+L)\le(1/2)f(x),$$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $L\gt0$ is a constant.

I want to show that $f$ has exponential decay, that is $$f(x)\le C\exp(bx)$$ for $x\ge 0$ and constants $b$ and $C$.

I had asked [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030006/question-on-exponential-decay) before, but that one turned out to be false. Again any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version turns out to be true.

$f(x)$ is continuous on the bounded closed interval $x \in [0,L]$.

So too is $g(x)=2^{x/L}f(x)$, as the product of two continuous functions.

So $g(x)$ achieves a maximum (call it $M$) on this interval, by the extreme value theorem.

$M$ is then a maximum for $g(x)$ on the positive real number line since for positive integer $n$ you have $g(x+nL)=2^{(x+nL)/L}f(x+nL) =  2^{x/L} 2^n f(x+nL) \le 2^{x/L} f(x) = g(x) \le M$

So you can take $C=\max(M,0)$ and $b = -\dfrac{\log_e(2)}{L}$ to give $f(x) \le C\exp(bx)$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have that, for an constant 
(And positive) $L$, that $$f(x+L)\leq \frac{1}{2}f(x)$$
This means that, as $x$ changes (increasing), $f(x)$ will decrease its value.
The easiest way to prove that this is an exponential decay is using differential equations. Consider an infinitesimal $L$ and try to develop the idea using the concept of derivatives. I think this is enough for you to start working on it.

Comment: L is a constant, you cant consider infinitesimal L